# Insert a view with a context using php?

Tags: views

I know I can insert a view using the following code:

```
 <?php
    $view = views_get_view('VIEWNAME');
    print $view->preview('default');
 ?>
```

In my view I have a contextual filter of user: name

When I insert this view using the Display Suite module I have this option from Display Suite:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to pass this context to the view, like Display Suite does, using php code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default value for the contextual filter through URL and then in your code use `$view->set_arguments()` to pass the argument.